# shell script for extracting line of file using awk

Tags: shell

I want, the selected lines of file to be print in output file side by side separated by space. Here what I have did so far,

for file in SAC*

do

```
awk 'FNR==2 {print $4}' $file >>exp 

awk 'FNR==3 {print $4}' $file >>exp

awk 'FNR==4 {print $4}' $file >>exp

awk 'FNR==5 {print $4}' $file >>exp

awk 'FNR==7 {print $4}' $file >>exp

awk 'FNR==8 {print $4}' $file >>exp

awk 'FNR==24 {print $0}' $file >>exp 

done
```

My output is:

```
XV

AMPY

BHZ

2012-08-15T08:00:00

2013-12-31T23:59:59
```

I want output should be

```
XV AMPY BHZ 2012-08-15T08:00:00  2013-12-31T23:59:59
```

Comment: show the input file contents

Comment: pipe the result to `tr -d '\n'`

Comment: Modify all `print $4` to `printf "%s ",$4` in your `awk` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the test data (only 9 rows, tho):

```
$ cat file
1 2 3 14
1 2 3 24
1 2 3 34
1 2 3 44
1 2 3 54
1 2 3 64
1 2 3 74
1 2 3 84
1 2 3 94
```

Then the awk. No need for that `for` loop in shell, awk can handle multiple files:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { 
    ORS=" "
    a[2];a[3];a[4];a[5];a[7];a[8]  # list of records for which $4 should be outputed
}
FNR in a { print $4 }              # output the $4s
FNR==9 { printf "%s\n",$0 }        # replace 9 with 24
' file file # ...                  # the files you want to process (SAC*)
24 34 44 54 74 84 1 2 3 94
24 34 44 54 74 84 1 2 3 94
```